# How to set up an SMS gateway

Tags: api, sms, gateway, bulksms

I'm ambitious to setup an SMS Gateway to provide SMS capability to multiple providers in India.

I want to provide the registered users the ability to add their own sender ID or even their mobile no. as sender ID (as 160By2 provide).

I have already explored the viability of a cellular phone based SMS gateway using Gnokii and some other proprietary stuff. But none of them are as we we all know any match to the capabilities of Bulk SMS Gateways.

I have an idea that we should sign some sort of contract with various wireless providers to be able to add messages to their SMS center queues.

I also would like to know the budget of such a setup :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to get an SMS gateway and build you app over that. You can buy a SMS gateway from a company like [this](http://www.clickatell.com/products/sms_gateway.php)/[smsxchange](http://www.smsxchange.com/main/default.asp) get a server on a lease and get it configured with [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/)

It totally depends on your requirement. If you want some thing like 160by2.com, then you just need to:

1. Buy a SMS Gateway
2. Build your app using thr APIs your SMS Gateway provider provides.

[Setting up, Configuring, and Using Kannel to send/receive SMS messages](http://www.chipmunkninja.com/Setting-up-Configuring-and-Using-13@)

If you want you OWN sms gateway then get a server and install Kannel or follow [this](http://www.x11.net/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_an_SMS_Gateway).

Comment: Hi zengr thanks for your informative reply, But I would also like to know how to get my own number as the sender id. That is a major feature of 160By2.com mundusms etc...